# How to change a file inside a .exe in python?

Tags: python, nsis

I've made a nsis installer for my application and want to change one of the files inside the installer .exe. Is there a way to open the installer and change one of the files inside, similar to ZipFile?
The reason for doing this is I want to add a unique token so I can later identify which user has downloaded the app. Generating a new installer from scratch with the token inside would be too slow.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) I would read through the NSIS documentation and find out how to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot change files inside the installer.

What you can do however is to append some text to the end of the exe on the server and then [read it in the installer](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/ReadCustomerData).

If you have a lot of data, you can append it in a .cab file and use the [CabX plug-in](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/CabX_plug-in) (CabX::FromSelf).

Comment: Thanks, the first idea worked perfectly.